# Replacing characters in URL

Tags: .htaccess

Input :
[https://example.com/?s=tèstà&post_type=product](https://example.com/?s=t%C3%A8st%C3%A0&post_type=product)

And I want to replace "è" with "e" and "à" with "a"

So output would be like :
https://example.com/?s=testa&post_type=product

I've tried everything but still couldn't fix this!

Is there a way to fix this by editing .htaccess file ?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `lodash` in javascript and use the `deburr` method to convert **Latin-1 Supplement** and **Latin Extended-A** letters to basic Latin letters and removing combining diacritical marks.

Lodash is good for performing various other operations also. You should try
[Lodash](https://lodash.com/).

```js
const str = _.deburr("https://example.com/?s=tèstà&post_type=product");
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```